# Why does it always pick a first TD cell in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in AngularJS and I'm trying to make a little game.

I have a table:

```
<table class="board">
<h1>Table</h1>
<input type="number" ng-model="val"><button ng-click="ctrl.foo(val)">PRESS</button>
    <tr ng-repeat="tr in ctrl.arr">
        <td ng-repeat="td in ctrl.arr" ng-click="ctrl.getIndex(tr, td)">{{ctrl.sign[$parent.$index][$index]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is the code for this table to mark the cell you click on:

```
this.foo = function(size){

        this.arr = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < size; i++){
            this.arr.push(i);
        }
    }
    this.getIndex = function(tr, td){

        this.sign = 'X';

        console.log(tr, td);
    }
```

Can someone explain why by click on any cell it's always mark only first cell?

Where is the mistake?

[Here is the example](http://jsfiddle.net/ufaj6kcm/6/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is that you are assigning ctrl.sign as a variable in ctrl.push, but are treating it as a 2d array when you reference it with the html code.

The reason you see 'x' in the first column can be shown by a small example (though I am not sure why, someone might be able to explain it... I assume it has to do with the way javascript handles variables)

```
var test = 'x';
console.log(test[0][0]); //shows 'x'
console.log(test[0][1]); // shows undefined
console.log(test[1][1]); // type error
```

So in your code, we can fix it by creating a 2d array, and using your existing method of inserting the 'x'. We will adjust foo to create / populate the 2d array, and push will do the insertion:

```
this.foo = function(size) {

    this.arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        this.arr.push(i);
        //fill our 2d array
        this.sign.push([]);
        for (var g = 0; g < size; g++) {
           this.sign[i].push(''); 
        }
    }
}
this.push = function(parent, index) {
   this.sign[parent][index] = 'X';
   console.log(parent, index)
}
```

At this point you could also swap out arr for sign on your ng-repeats.  Please see the working [jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/d3hszefb/1/)

Comment: thanks you very very mush for such a full explanation :)